# Post wall message on facebook account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement some functionality in a blackberry app, that I saw in other application.

Basically it's a window that has a message, and a Facebook icon. When you click on the icon it launches a new window, this window asks the user for permissions(user and password), and then the message is posted in the user's wall.
So my question is how can I replicate that?. I have been looking at the graph api, but I just can't figure out how to do all of this in one step. I mean just typing the url in the browser, and some post data.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Facebook BlackBerry SDK project? [Facebook BlackBerry SDK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk)